# Is it possible to pass a struct's member variable as parameter

Tags: c++

I am trying to associate a struct's member variable with a class. So that when I create a new class, I can specify that it is associated with this member variable in a struct. For example:

```
struct A {
  int a;
  int b;
};

static A a[2];
a[0].a = 1;
a[0].b = 2;
a[1].a = 3;
a[1].b = 4;

class foo {
 public:
  foo(int index, ???) {
    c = a[index].???;  //Is it possible to define the 2nd parameter as a getter of struct A's member? So this line could resolve to either a[index].a or a[index].b?
  }
 private:
  int c;
};
```

So that:

- new foo(0, ???) would set c to 1 given ??? refer to A::a
- new foo(0, ???) would set c to 2 given ??? refer to A::b
- new foo(1, ???) would set c to 3 given ??? refer to A::a
- new foo(1, ???) would set c to 4 given ??? refer to A::b

Comment: Pointer-to-member, perhaps? Your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you need to pass a data member pointer:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

static A a[2]
{
    1, 2
,   3, 4
};

class foo
{
    public: int c;

    public:
    foo(int const index, int A::* const p_field)
    {
        c = a[index].*p_field;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo const f1(0, &A::a);
    ::std::cout << f1.c << ::std::endl;
    foo const f2(0, &A::b);
    ::std::cout << f2.c << ::std::endl;
    foo const f3(1, &A::a);
    ::std::cout << f3.c << ::std::endl;
    foo const f4(1, &A::b);
    ::std::cout << f4.c << ::std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Check this code at online compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbac88d3076dbbaa)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options. If you just want the integer (like you have in your code you've posted), then just take an integer as a parameter to the constructor and pass it the right number.

```
class foo {
 public:
  foo(int val) {
    c = val
  }
 private:
  int c;
};

int main() {
    foo f(a[0].b);
}
```

Or you could take a reference to an integer. This way if one changes, the other will as well:

```
class foo {
 public:
  foo(int &val) : c(val) { } //need to use an initialization list for this one
 private:
  int &c;
};

int main() {
    foo f(a[0].b);
    a[0].b = -1; //f.c will be -1 now as well
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a data member pointer as in VTT's answer is the most direct solution but I often find member pointers and member function pointer syntax a bit cumbersome and I believe it is hard for the compiler to optimize.

For these kind of things I prefer to use a stateless lambda. You can pass a lambda to a function template and then the compiler can easily optimize it away:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  int a;
  int b;
};

static A a[2]{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

class foo {
public:
  int c;
public:
  template<typename F>
  foo(int index, F getter) { c = getter(a[index]); }
};

int main() {
  auto agetter = [](const A& a){ return a.a; };
  auto bgetter = [](const A& a){ return a.b; };

  foo const f1(0, agetter);
  std::cout << f1.c << "\n";
  foo const f2(0, bgetter);
  std::cout << f2.c << "\n";
  foo const f3(1, agetter);
  std::cout << f3.c << "\n";
  foo const f4(1, bgetter);
  std::cout << f4.c << "\n";
}
```